# Alloy ListView with static Header

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Is it possible to make the `ListView`'s `HeaderView` static such that it does not scroll off?

```
<ListView id="agreementListView" onItemclick = "itemClickAgrmt" class="elementsList" defaultItemTemplate="finAgreement" >
    <HeaderView>
        <View class="row" >
            <Label class="lblAgr col1">Finance</Label>
            <Label class="lblAgr col2">Duration</Label>
            <Label class="lblAgr col3">Monthly</Label>
            <Label class="lblAgr col4">Down</Label>
        </View>
    </HeaderView>
    <Templates>
```

This `HeaderView` shows up like another row at the top that scrolls away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. The `HeaderView` is stick with the `ListView` and scroll with it. If you want a static view, just add a view before the `ListView` on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes to this question, here's the summary to handle the HeaderView scrolling.

**On iOS:**

- Putting the `HeaderView` inside the `ListSection` will always make it stick to the top until next header-view comes up.
- Putting the `HeaderView` right inside the `ListView` (not the `ListSection`) will always scroll it along with the `ListItems` and won't receive the `onItemclick` event.

**On Android:**

- HeaderView will always scroll wherever it is put.